# Permission Denied on Xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode, permissions, xcode4

I'm getting error message about permission denied, when I build any app on Xcode 4:

> error: unable to create '/Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JewBack-ejcsrvhiqaxnzmdheqdhshjvwjng/Build/Products' (Permission denied)

There's other error message, too:

> Check dependencies
>   ProcessInfoPlistFile /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JewBack-ejcsrvhiqaxnzmdheqdhshjvwjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JewBack.app/Info.plist JewBack-Info.plist
>       cd /Users/mike/Downloads/JewBack
>       setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       builtin-infoPlistUtility JewBack-Info.plist -genpkginfo /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JewBack-ejcsrvhiqaxnzmdheqdhshjvwjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JewBack.app/PkgInfo -expandbuildsettings -format binary -platform iphonesimulator -o /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JewBack-ejcsrvhiqaxnzmdheqdhshjvwjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JewBack.app/Info.plist
>   error: couldn't create directory /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JewBack-ejcsrvhiqaxnzmdheqdhshjvwjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JewBack.app: Permission deniederror: couldn't create directory /Users/mike/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/JewBack-ejcsrvhiqaxnzmdheqdhshjvwjng/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/JewBack.app: Permission deniederror: The file “Info.plist” doesn’t exist.

Comment: **The file “Info.plist” doesn’t exist.** looks suspicious .. does it exist in your project? Either way, try a **Clean Build**.

Comment: @WrightsCS how do you do clean build??

Comment: @WrightsCS yeah info.plist exists its under resources folder on xCode 4 on my prject the .plist tells me like icon file and bundle name and the infodictionary version

Comment: **`COMMAND + K`** to Clean Build.

Comment: JewBack? Do I even want to know?? lol…

Comment: I had the same error and then removing the platform (iOS) and adding it again through terminal command line helped. Although, I must say I had to try it n number of times before it worked. Thanks

Answer (score 23):

Ok. It seems you may be restricted to create Build Folder in your system. Try out the procedure below which creates a Build Folder in project folder itself.

In  **Xcde** menu bar go to: **Preferences**  >  **Locations** Tab. In **Locations** change **Derived Data** to **Relative** and set any name in the text box. I have used "Build". This folder will be created in your project folder for built binaries.

Comment: Is that pretty much it and it will like save it there from now on I Noticed it bionary thing

Comment: ok. welcome. keep accepting answers if you solved your problem.

Comment: yes this changes are done in XCode, so from now onwards in all project, all builts are save under project's folder.

Comment: I had this happen after I moved hella project files while doing some organization. This fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

please check your Xcode version and upgrade your Xcode. early I was using Xcode 6.1 and I got error message with that Xcode version after then I upgrade Xcode Version 6.2. now It is working perfectly. when you upgrade your OS X version You should upgrade Xcode version.