# Error cleaning build folder - You do not have required file permissions

Tags: xcode6

I'm using xcode 6. Its fine to clean but it fails when I choose clean build folders.

[image]

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Seems like you are restricted to create a build folder in your system root.

In `XCode Menu --> Preferences --> Locations Tab --> Locations sub-tab`, Change `Derived Data` to `Relative` and give any name in text box.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8109468/permission-denied-on-xcode-4) which is also a permission problem in Xcode.

Comment: Same as above, but I only needed to toggle from Default->Relative->Default.  Seemed to reset it and now it works. Xcode 6.1

Comment: Just to confirm that the toggle also/still works in XCode 6.3.1 (for me at least).

Comment: I had to toggle a couple of times. Make sure the error window is closed.

Comment: Also just to confirm that the toggle also/still works in Xcode 7 GM (for me at least)

Comment: Works for me by toggle from Default->Relative->Default. Thanks @mcm!

Comment: Update to confirm toggle Default => Relative => Default works in Xcode 7.1.1

Comment: Wonder how to give it permission ?

Comment: Just toggling Default -> Relative -> Default didn't work for me. Tried that several times. What did work for me was Default -> Relative -> Close Xcode -> Reopen XCode -> toggle back to Default. That worked on the first try. Xcode 7.2.1.

Comment: @ErikvanderNeut Absolutely true! Looks like your solution is default now. As it works in all versions of Xcode. I am running 7.3

Comment: Sadly, no combination of this worked for me. I'm on XCode 7.3.1, but a very old project - but I've definitely been getting this since XCode 6. My problem is a little different - I only get the error when I switch targets or switch simulators/devices, and randomly sometimes when I try to clean build folder the first time. If I try to clean the build folder a second time it usually works afterward.

Answer (score 7):

It could be due to Xcode bug (at least for me in Xcode 6.3.1). Toggling the location for derived data folder will fix it.

Go to **Xcode > Preferences > Locations** and change **Derived Data** to **Relative**, then back to **Default**.

Clean build folder again.

Answer (score 0):

I just clean that folder in Finder, then all fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode 14 I clicked "Clean" command which had popped up in the 3rd row from the top and that fixed it.